# I can't add StatusCode field to forms and views in List Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

We are using Dynamics 365 Sales. Its version is  9.2.21073

I try to add statuscode field to forms and views in the MarketingList entity. But I can't see that field options like below.

StatusCode of other entities can add to forms. How can I add the field on the form?

[image]

Comment: I observed this behavior too, maybe this is by design. :(

Comment: That made me sad.

Answer (score -1):

It might already be on the form.

The default is to only show "unused" fields. There is an option to turn that off

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, it is not. I checked different organizations in Dynamics 365 Sales 9.2, I couldn't add statuscode field to form for MarketingList entity.